# Could I make a magnetic foam or film by mixing magnetic dust?

Tags: magnetic-fields, geomagnetism

I'm a developer and tinkerer more than an academic, and I'm not sure if this question, being more practical and less theoretical, will be welcome or not here. But here goes, with apologies in advance if it's bad form...

I need to (affordably) construct a very large ferromagnetic sphere, about 18" in diameter. I need it to be much more magnetic than household rubber/refrigerator magnets, but an electromagnet would be overkill. Magnetism comparable to the neodymium magnets you can buy in hardware stores and hobby shops would be perfect, but if it was as magnetic as solid carbon steel or iron or nickel, that would be great too.

It's cost prohibitive to have an 18" steel sphere machined, but I have a hollow 18" polycarbonate sphere I'd like to line with a magnetic material somehow. So on to my question(s):

If I mixed neodymium dust or iron dust with some sort of hardenable putty, could I create a magnetic filler? Or would the granules just orient in such a way to have no real outside magnetism? That is what I suspect.

Might there be a process to make a magnetic putty in which the magnetic particles orient in such a way to make the hardened form highly magnetic? Perhaps spreading it out over plastic-covered carbon steel, letting it set halfway, and then shaping it around a curved form?

Are there any semi-flexible materials with strong magnetism that could be shaped into a sphere?

Any advice or insight appreciated. And again, apologies if this is an awkward place to pose this sort of question!

**Clarification:** It doesn't necessarily need to *attract*, as long as magnets stick strongly to it.

Comment: A wrecking ball should be magnetic, I believe. Cut it in half (I would suggest asking a ship yard or steel foundry for help) and place permanent magnets between the two halves. Sounds like a bit of a "don't do this at home kids" kind of project, but if you really, really, really "need" the thingumbob... that's how you can make one.

Comment: @CuriousOne Ha, that sounds really fun! But I should have mentioned, it needs to be hollow, and fairly light (well, at least not wrecking ball heavy). And I need to be able to open it up; I actually have a bunch of electronics to put into it. Hence my looking for some kind of flexible film or putty that I could line the shell with.

Comment: If it's hollow, it won't give you the field of a sphere. Maybe it would be better if you told us what you are trying to do rather than coming up with probably the worst possible way of doing it.

Comment: @CuriousOne When I tell, people go on and on about the worst ways to do it, trading my one problem for a hundred others. I've already solved a lot, and I'm down to this one. I have a complex object contained in an 18" spherical shape, that I need magnets to stick to. If it were a hollow steel shell, that would work. But if I could line the insides of a plastic sphere with a ferromagnetic material, whether it's some kind of magnetic putty, or molded metal, or... chain mail? Ha, anything... Then I could do it much much more efficiently. Just need to find/make a flexible magnetic substance.

Comment: That's fair. I apologize for the misunderstanding. To a physicist a magnetized sphere of 18 inches in diameter is essentially a wrecking ball. What you need is merely a thin walled magnetic shell. The materials you are thinking about exist commercially in form of flexible ferrite sheets, but I have not seen any with magnetic properties that are much better than those of  refrigerator magnets. That doesn't mean one can't do better, but it may be not trivial to actually get better results. Did you consider having two steel sphere halves hammered by a coach builder?

Comment: Just buy lots of small neodymium magnets get two spheres of a small difference in diameter and glue the neodymium magnets in the gap between them. Fill the remainder gap with iron dust if you want. The thing is that you will have a stronger field right next to the magnets in comparison to the gaps. If that's ok then go for it.

Comment: @CuriousOne Ooh, hadn't heard of a coach builder. I wonder how much that would cost. Any ideas where to start?

Comment: @Kurtovic I had thought of that, but I need the field to be pretty smooth all around the globe.

Comment: Well you cant have a smooth field by definition. The magnetic field is divergence free (sourceless). So you need 2 poles on any magnet (like earth for example). You probably thougth of smoothness in this sense but yeah. You can smooth it out by putting another ferromagnetic sphere around the proposed configuration. Look at internam permanent magnet synchronous machine rotors. They could give you an idea even though they are cylindrical.

Comment: @Kurtovic Sounds like overthinking. It doesn't need to attract at all, let alone smoothly, it just needs to be evenly magnetic. Meaning it could be a 1mm sheet of steel if I could get it into a spherical shape.

Comment: [Alibaba](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/1-4-18-Mild-Steel-Half_60614994318.html?spm=a2700.7724838.2017115.107.16ceb061cQBNOp). These seeme to be used for [firepits](https://www.google.ca/search?client=ubuntu&biw=1206&bih=669&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=LgYiWrfPKsncjwPht6G4Cg&q=steel+hemisphere+fire&oq=steel+hemisphere+fire&gs_l=psy-ab.3...23714.26154.0.27469.4.4.0.0.0.0.114.409.2j2.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.113...0i24k1.0.0POk32HPfs4).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a field that is radially symmetric, it is not possible.  It would amount to constructing a magnetic monopole.  Making it appear to be a dipole, though, is entirely possible.

You might consider using a UV-curable resin of the sort that dentists use.  That way you could orient and cure small portions of your sphere at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think ferromagnetic dust (or filings) with some adhesive should work. If the resulting mix has zero average magnetization, you should be able to magnetize it using an external magnet. Beware of the so-called soft iron (zero average magnetization after the external field is removed).

You may wish to try it first with a small amount of mix.

Comment: while your idea is good the problem is that such a mixture will have too low a dust/fillings surface density, which is to say the amount of dust/filling would be inssuficient to attract magnets well (i am sticking with the asker's idea to stick magnets to the sphere). Technically it all depends on exactly what KIND of dust/fillings and what magnets but in the general case, using common materials it will not work out well.

Comment: @mathgenius: I am not sure I understand your comment. I don't think the surface density is very relevant. There is no direct contact of the magnets and the ferromagnetic powder, as they interact through the plastic sphere anyway.

Comment: My reputation isn't high enough to mark this helpful, but it is, thanks! Some additional thoughts: Without ferromagnetic dust handy (yet), I've been tinkering a little bit. I have a thick flat sheet of plastic the same width/density as the spherical shell. When I put a thin flat sheet (less than 1mm) of carbon steel behind it, the magnets stick very well. So the question is, could iron dust or neodymium dust mixed with a filler be as magnetically responsive as 1mm of steel? Getting that would solve my problem!

Comment: akhmeteli, sorry, i do not know WHY i wrote "surface" density, i meant the general density

@KevinCogill, i could be wrong but i think it will only work if you apply a thick layer of such a mixture. It really depends on what you use as a binding agent/glue you could do some tests on that sheet of plastic try it with a single coat of the mixture and then try letting it set and making it thicker to see if it will work. Honestly - i don't know

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to achieve what you are asking of, however the better and more efficient the way - the more costly it is (as with everything :) ).

You *could* try to make a mixture of a ferromagnetic substance with an adhesive one, like akhmeteli has suggested, but like i commented on his answer - is you use common or widely available materials, the mixture would not be able to attract magnets strongly enough for any normal magnet to actually stick strongly to it. And if you opt to use more special materials, I think it would be better to just try the following:

You can *coat* your sphere in a ferromagnetic coating. I think there exist ferromagnetic paints or something similar, i am just recalling an idea from the back of my mind, i am not sure about it, but you can just make metal sheets, copper or aluminum ones should be light enough, which you can then attach/bolt/etc. to your sphere to give it a strong outer ferromagnetic outside.
A more radical approach would be to go to a steel mill and have your sphere coated in LIQUID METAL, which when cools off should stick to it pretty well, but you probably cannot do that. XD

On a related note: I am not certain of you sphere's melting or burning point, but there *could* be some metals that have a melting point below its melting/burning point and thus you can grab a bucket of such a metal in liquid form and coat the sphere in it, assuming one exists and is ferromagnetic enough.

Comment: Coating the sphere is not an option, and the melting point of the plastic is far lower than any ferromagnetic metal I can think of.
On the upside though, the magnets on the outside can be super powerful. As it stands, I'm using 10mm neodymium spherical magnets. If the mixture is as ferromagnetic as 1mm of carbon steel, I'll be just fine.